# Logarithmic differential forms are holomorphic or not?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry

Let $\mathbb C_*^n = \{ z = (z_1, \ldots, z_n) \in \mathbb C^n | z_i \neq z_j \text{ for } i \neq j \}$ be the complex configuration space. Let us consider the logarithmic differential 1-forms $\omega_{i,j} = d\log(z_i-z_j) = \frac{dz_i - dz_j}{z_i - z_j}$. My question is that the differential 1-form $\omega_{i,j}$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb C_*^n$ or not? Thanks in advance for some answers.

Ps: My goal is to show that any Chen's iterated integral of the logarithmic differential 1-forms $\omega_{i,j}$ along $\gamma$ (a piecewise smooth path on $\mathbb C_*^n$) is homotopy invariant. Now, we can  obviously explain this claim by using the fact that the differential 1-forms $\{\omega_{i,j}\}_{1 \leq i < j \leq n}$ are holomorphic on $\mathbb C_*^n$.

Comment: Is this differential-geometry ? Looks like calculus to me.
Maybe it is me but I do not get it. The log is a differentiable function so why would that not be holomorphic ? 
But in particular why does it matter ? What is the context or goal here ?
Seems random. Please add context.

Comment: Thanks dear Mr/Ms. Mick. I just added my goal.

Comment: Doesn't this simply reduce to asking whether ${dz\over z}$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb C-\{0\}$?

Comment: But is this not asking about homotopy between curves of different dimensions ?

Comment: Yes, thanks @paul garrett. We have  that any $\omega_{i,j}$ is equal to the full-back $P_{i,j}^* (dz/z)$, where $P_{i,j}: \mathbb C_*^n \to \mathbb C- \{0\}, z \mapsto z_i - z_j$.